# not load image to graphicImages

Tags: jsf, graphicimage

I want to use h:graphicImage but somehow could not find the correct source address image does not appear

Where am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the correct url of your image. The url depends on how you deployed the images folder, it could be /your_application_context/resources/images/avatar.png

Comment: but this code is working
<h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap.min.css" library="css"></h:outputStylesheet>

Does not work with the same logic?

Comment: Yes, the logic is different. The <h:outputStylesheet /> searches the css file you give it inside the path /resources/library where library is the value of the library attribute. In your case he loads the file /resources/css/bootstrap.min.css.
Another example. On my classpath I included the primefaces jar and inside it I have the file jquery.js inside the folder /META-INF/resources/primefaces/jquery.
To load the file i use <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />